# how to show different message on required and invalid?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, validation, angularjs-directive

can you please tell me how to show different message on required and invalid ?In other word .make a  form from json using plugin  .In that there are some required  parameter .and some I need to validate example "Email".When user press "submit" button if user did not fill the field it show "this field is required" .and if user fill the value but not same patten than it say "invalid value".can we show different message as different situation .

i used this plugin
https://github.com/Textalk/angular-schema-form/blob/master/docs/index.md#validation-messages
and I make this plunker
http://plnkr.co/edit/ZNJO3x3IqajjdMNStJMF?p=preview

```
angular.module('test',['schemaForm']).controller('FormController', function($scope,$http){
   $scope.schema = {
    type: "object",
    properties: {
      name: { type: "string", minLength: 2, title: "Name", description: "Name or alias" ,required:true,"default": "dddd"},
      "student": { type: "string", title: "studentname", description: "Name or student" ,required:false},

      "email": {
      "title": "Email",
      "type": "string",
       "pattern":"\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*",

      "description": "Email will be used for evil.",
      required:true
    },
      title: {
        type: "string",
        required:true,
        enum: ['dr','jr','sir','mrs','mr','NaN','dj'],

      }
    }
  };

  $scope.form = [
    "*",
    {
      type: "submit",
      title: "Save"
    }
  ];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you may read from the [official angular-schema-form documentation](https://github.com/Textalk/angular-schema-form/blob/master/docs/index.md#validation-messages)

> **Per default all error messages comes from the schema validator tv4**, this might or might not work for you. If you supply a validationMessage property in the form definition, and if its value is a string that will be used instead on any validation error.
>
> **If you need more fine grained control you can supply an object instead with keys matching the error codes of tv4. See tv4.errorCodes**
>
> Ex.
>
> ```
> {
>   key: "address.street",
>   validationMessage: {
>     tv4.errorCodes.STRING_LENGTH_SHORT: "Address is too short, man.",
>     "default": "Just write a proper address, will you?"   //Special catch all error message
>   }
> }
> ```
>
> You can also set a global validationMessage in formDefaults see Global Options.

So for more error messages, visit this [link](https://github.com/geraintluff/tv4)

Comment: can you share plunker

Answer (score 0):

Here is a great blog article that should answer your question: http://www.thebhwgroup.com/blog/2014/08/designing-html-forms-angularjs-part-1/

In particular, check out part 3 "Validation Messages and Styling".

From the article,

```
<span class="validation-message" ng-show="contactForm.firstName.$error.maxlength">Max length 20</span>
```

Where the ng-form is named `contactForm` and the element in question is named `firstName`. This puts the form on the scope and you can then traverse that to get the errors, and show an error message specifically for each error.