# how to remove this this Unexpected token error in angular js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-schema-form

I am trying to display different message in form .I make form from json while study of this documentation
https://github.com/Textalk/angular-schema-form/blob/master/docs/index.md#validation-messages

Plunker
http://plnkr.co/edit/ZNJO3x3IqajjdMNStJMF?p=preview

when I write this like as given in doc I am not able view the page as well getting the error?

```
 validationMessage: {
    tv4.errorCodes.STRING_LENGTH_SHORT: "Address is too short, man.",
    "default": "Just write a proper address, will you?"   //Special catch all error message
  },
```

I need to display different msg when user valid validate ?

Comment: Could you please elaborate? I can't understand what you want and your plunkr throws no error at all.

Comment: @Fedaykin I just want to show different message ..in form so I study doc and found that there is a way to show different message using that t4

Comment: I have same problem and some one answer also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25330571/how-to-show-different-message-on-required-and-invalid/25333691#25333691 .I used same example.did you get it now ?I just want to show different validation message at different stage

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the constant `tv4.errorCodes.STRING_LENGTH_SHORT` does not exist in your code for some reason. You can always use the raw values or make an angular constant with them and use it like this:

```
"email": {
    "title": "Email",
    "type": "string",
    "minLength": 2,
    "pattern": "^\\S+@\\S+$",
    validationMessage: {
        200: "Address is too short, man.",
        "default": "Just write a proper address, will you?" //Special catch all error message
    },
    "description": "Email will be used for evil.",
    required: true
  },
```

I just added the minLength requirement so it actually can get validated.

You can check the error code values on the official package: https://github.com/geraintluff/tv4/blob/master/tv4.js

Or simply refer to these:

```
var ErrorCodes = {
    INVALID_TYPE: 0,
    ENUM_MISMATCH: 1,
    ANY_OF_MISSING: 10,
    ONE_OF_MISSING: 11,
    ONE_OF_MULTIPLE: 12,
    NOT_PASSED: 13,
    // Numeric errors
    NUMBER_MULTIPLE_OF: 100,
    NUMBER_MINIMUM: 101,
    NUMBER_MINIMUM_EXCLUSIVE: 102,
    NUMBER_MAXIMUM: 103,
    NUMBER_MAXIMUM_EXCLUSIVE: 104,
    // String errors
    STRING_LENGTH_SHORT: 200,
    STRING_LENGTH_LONG: 201,
    STRING_PATTERN: 202,
    // Object errors
    OBJECT_PROPERTIES_MINIMUM: 300,
    OBJECT_PROPERTIES_MAXIMUM: 301,
    OBJECT_REQUIRED: 302,
    OBJECT_ADDITIONAL_PROPERTIES: 303,
    OBJECT_DEPENDENCY_KEY: 304,
    // Array errors
    ARRAY_LENGTH_SHORT: 400,
    ARRAY_LENGTH_LONG: 401,
    ARRAY_UNIQUE: 402,
    ARRAY_ADDITIONAL_ITEMS: 403,
    // Custom/user-defined errors
    FORMAT_CUSTOM: 500,
    KEYWORD_CUSTOM: 501,
    // Schema structure
    CIRCULAR_REFERENCE: 600,
    // Non-standard validation options
    UNKNOWN_PROPERTY: 1000
};
```

Note that the `STRING_LENGTH_SHORT` value is 200.

Here is a working plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/4EwGzl1LlseNYOX802S1?p=preview

If you want tho learn more about angular constants/values, check this out: http://lostechies.com/gabrielschenker/2014/01/14/angularjspart-9-values-and-constants/

Putting those values on a constant so they can be easily reused would make a good exercise for you.

Hope that helps

Comment: thanks fredayin .i have Question .if you check "pattern": "^\\S+@\\S+$",..when you write any thing example "a@d" is giving true why ?I change min length "2".email should come like "a@g.com" http://plnkr.co/edit/wbziK5aRUg69JuwXDoVy?p=preview

Comment: Well that´s another matter. Search for email address validation regex and replace it there, that should do the trick.